# Cant start ubuntu 3d after installing the nvidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, myunity

I just performed a clean install of ubuntu 12.04, installed the "experimental nvidia drivers" from "additional drivers" screen. Even if i choose "ubuntu" when logging in ubuntu 2d runs. I have geforce 540m. I dont know if i gave enough information but there is my problem. Thanks in advance!

note: English isnt my native language so please excuse grammar mistakes.

Comment: Google your graphics card to see if its compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Painful answer but generally the only way to fix these issues is to download the proprietry drivers from nvidia for linux and then uninstall the experimental drivers and install the proprietry ones.

this link should help you resolve your issue:-

[Nvidia 295.59 released](http://www.unixmen.com/nvidia-driver-295-59-released-install-in-ubuntu-12-04-linuxmint13-fedora17-arch-gentoo/)

Hope this helps.